# How can I show only the current directory after the prompt in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, bashrc

I have tried the suggestions here:

[How to shorten the no of characters display for the current directory in the prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/125559/how-to-shorten-the-no-of-characters-display-for-the-current-directory-in-the-pro)

But adding these lines to the .bashrc file had no effect.

Uname -a :

#46-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 13:47:05 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What did you add to the `.bashrc`? Have you started a new shell after changing `.bashrc`? What is the new prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - the question is already answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/186743/how-do-i-only-display-the-base-dir-in-my-ubuntu-terminal)

In the standard .bashrc on Ubuntu (in your home directory), look for the comment 'If this is an Xterm...' and change the PS1 value beneath.